# Flex, Ant and TeamCity

Tags: apache-flex, ant, teamcity

Is anyone using TeamCity for building their Flex apps? We're using .Net for our main site code and backend flex data calls and we use flex for our application. I have a working Ant build script, but I can't get it to run with the TeamCity Ant Runner. I'm curious if anyone has gotten this working and if they have, could I potentitially see a sample of your build script?

For some reason the build script won't pick up the FLEX_HOME environment variables for the Flex Ant Tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a previous project I worked on we had exactly the same situation as you and it can work. I can't remember doing anything special to get this going although we may have had to manually set some environment variables in the TeamCity config. Check out the [TeamCity docs](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/6.Properties+and+environment+variables) for how to set these and how to they are [used](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Using+Properties)

You might also try using the basic Command line runner to see if that works. When troubleshooting environment variable issues in TeamCity I have found it useful to have part of the build process run a DOS *set* command (*env* for Linux) and then look in the build logs to see what the actual environment is.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Brett. I eventually got it going. I had to un-install a bunch of programs on the build server. They had FlexBuilder 2 and FlexBuilder 3 installed on the same box. Plus a few version of Java. Now it's all cleaning and building perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see why it shouldn´t work. Just declare FLEX_HOME in the top of your Ant script, and point to the sdk on the TeamCity machine, like:

```
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="c:/adobe/flex/sdk/3.3"/>
```